# Meteor - Meteorite package paths change when each git user runs "mrt update"

Tags: git, meteor, meteorite

I'm working on a Meteor app with another dev, using git for version control.

With annoying frequency, changes like the following appear in git:

```
packages/iron-router
@@ -1 +1 @@

-/Users/theirname/.meteorite/packages/iron-router/EventedMind/iron-router/<hash>
+/Users/myname/.meteorite/packages/iron-router/EventedMind/iron-router/<samehash>
```

The only "change" to the package is the path, caused by us using different computers (which shouldn't be a surprise). I would've figured Meteorite would be smart enough to handle this sort of thing more seamlessly.

Is there a way to prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally, this folder should be excluded from version control: you are supposed to have a `.gitignore` file in your `packages` folder that's being updated automatically whenever you add a package with `mrt add ...`.

Indeed, you don't have to version-control the packages: `meteorite` will find and download them itself upon first run.

Think of it the same way as with the `npm` packages: `node_modules` folder is usually excluded from the version control.

However, there's a chance that at least some of your packages (`iron-router`, for example) are already under version control, so they won't be affected by the `.gitignore` and the symlink changes will still be committed. Just make sure to do `git rm -rf packages/iron-router` then.

Comment: `packages/.gitignore` already listed those two packages, but as you say, probably they somehow slipped into version control earlier (though I didn't know that .gitignore is... ignored by git in such circumstances). 

I tried the command you mentioned, and I'll see if it works over the next few days.